Praying in a room with pictures
If praying in a room with pictures is haram (as some scholars say), then is the prayer itself valid?

I don't know about those scholars, my guess is that pictures could be hidden idols, and that would be clearly haram. But you are praying to Allah, and not to the pictures.

Alhamdulillah,
The presence of such pictures or images does not invalidate the prayer itself, as long as the person is not actively venerating or worshipping them during the prayer.
And Allah knows best!

I will give a valid fatwa to your answer -
[https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://islamqa.info/en/answers/161222/can-you-pray-in-a-room-with-pictures&ved=2ahUKEwjS1K_E-JSJAxUIa2wGHShMFnUQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0BgXlx7IpJ9_rdI1Fs4kgc]

Summary of answer: The scholars unanimously agreed that it is not
allowed to pray in a place in which there are images of animate
beings. In fact some of them were of the view that doing so is
prohibited, although the view of the majority is that it is disliked.


A link to a google search is like looking at the clouds in the sky: it changes every minute.

@GyroGearloose sorry, that is a preview page link as you can see the original url is in &url=... This is the fatwa link, the first part is a header not needed
